# Ouput all the page's media queries in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, media-queries

Using JavaScript, what would be the best way to output a list containing all media queries that are being applied to the current page.

I assume this would need to filtering to find embedded media queries i.e.

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 30em)" href="/css/30em.css">`

as well as media queries located in CSS files, i.e.

`@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {}`

An example output of what I'm looking for:

```
<p>There are 3 media queries loaded on this page</p>
<ol>
    <li>30em</li>
    <li>40em</li>
    <li>960px</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C2y8Q/1/) with the code to list the media queries that are being applied to the current page

JavaScript:

```
var mediaQueryCount = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $links = $('link[rel="stylesheet"]');
    $.each($links, function(i, item){
        if(item.media){
            mediaQueryCount++;
            var start = item.media.indexOf('(')+1;
            var end = item.media.indexOf(')');
            var str = item.media.substring(start, end);
            var listItem = $('<li />',{
                html: str.split(':')[1]
            }).appendTo("#result");
        }
    });
    $('#totalMedia').text(mediaQueryCount);
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 30em)" />
        <link rel="stylesheet"  media="only screen and (min-width: 40em)"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  media="only screen and (min-width: 960px)"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>There are <span id="totalMedia"></span> media queries loaded on this page</p>
        <ol id="result">
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`MediaQueryList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MediaQueryList) object:

> A MediaQueryList object maintains a list of media queries on a document, and handles sending notifications to listeners when the media queries on the document change.

A related article by Nicholas C. Zakas:

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/01/03/css-media-queries-in-javascript-part-1/

---

Another option is using `styleSheets` property of the `document` object.

```
var $ol = $('<ol/>');

var styleSheet = document.styleSheets;
$.each(styleSheet, function(i, styleObject) {
   $.each(styleObject.cssRules, function(i, rule){  
      if (rule.media) {
          $ol.append(rule.media[0]) // only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px)
       }  
   }) 
}) 
var len = $ol.find('li').length;
$('p').text('There are ' + len + ' media queries loaded on this page')
$('body').append($ol)
```

Comment: Thanks! A Fiddle example would be great.

Comment: Just fyi http://caniuse.com/#search=MediaQueryList and also a `matchMedia()` polyfill you may find useful: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/blob/master/matchMedia.js

Comment: this just causes a CORS issue and fails.

Answer (score 2):

Please checkout this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YR3cs/). I used @sureshunivers code to parse and create li list.

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets;  //contains an object of all loaded stylesheets
var rules = sheets[i].cssRules; //The rules variable is list of all the rules of the current stylesheet represented as CSSRule objects.
```

Checkout this article- [Reacting to media queries in javascript](http://tylergaw.com/articles/reacting-to-media-queries-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for that *Reacting to media queries in javascript* article. EXACTLY what I was looking for